# MUTEX process synchronization - why does common lock variable not work?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, mutex

In college powerpoint slides of mine the teacher wrote that this solution for the MUTEX problem does not work. why?

lock = true means there already is a process in a critical section

1. Process1 checks lock and sees it is false
2. Process2 interrupts Process1
3. Process2 checks lock and it is still false
4. Process2 sets lock to true and enters the critical section
5. Process1 CHECKS lock AGAIN, sets it to true and enters the critical section. (how? why isnt it read as true, so it can't enter?)

Comment: Posting an actual solution would help us to understand why it doesn't work... I have a couple of guessess, but I won't comment until I see the code.

Comment: If in your program if you are creating more than one threads and as you know more than one thread could run at the same time so what  may happened is that let say both thread read the lock variable as false at the same time and both allows to enter it in critical code section. and also let say due to your hardware or any other reason, only one tread runs at a time then also this race condition can occur due to thread scheduling

Comment: there was no code in the slides. those 5 steps are just as they are in the slides, only translated to english from german. I assume this has something to do with getting and setting the lock valuenot being one atomic operation  (or is it sth else?) , but i dont understand why it isnt atomic.

Comment: It is really impossible to understand what the teacher meant. Basically, it is said here that something doesn't work because of so and so. But since we do not have any idea what this something is, it is not possible to tell you what are the issues there, other than just rephrasing those 5 slides, but that won't be of much help, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your 'lock' variable is just a variable, then the code to check a variable's value and then conditionally set that variable can be more than one instruction.

Consider the following psuedocode implementation:

- Read 'locked' into register A
- Compare register A to zero
- If compare was false, skip to the end
- Write '1' to 'locked'.

For instance, consider this code in C#:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static int locked = 0;

    private static bool GetLock()
    {
        if( locked == 0 )
        {
            locked = 1;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And consider its disassembly:

```
            if( locked == 0 )
00000000  cmp         dword ptr [0003E4F0h],0 
00000007  jne         0000000000000019 
            {
                locked = 1;
00000009  mov         dword ptr [0003E4F0h],1 
                return true;
00000013  mov         eax,1 
00000018  ret 
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
00000019  xor         eax,eax 
0000001b  ret
```

Now consider what happens when two threads are trying to do this at the same time:

- Thread 1: reads that 'locked' is 0, enters the 'if' statement.
- OS thread scheduler decides to change which thread is on the CPU
- OS puts thread 2 on the CPU.
- Thread 2: reads that 'locked' is 0, enters the 'if' statement
- Thread 2: writes '1' to 'locked' to indicate it acquired it.
- Thread 2: returns true indicating it acquired it.
- OS thread scheduler decides to change which thread is on the CPU
- OS puts thread 1 on the CPU.
- Thread 1: already in the 'if' statement, so it executes its next instruction
- Thread 1: writes '1' to 'locked' to indicate it acquired it

  - But woops, the variable was already set to 1 because someone else acquired it.
- Thread 1: returns true to indicate it thinks it acquired the lock (it didn't).

And now whatever thread 1 and thread 2 are doing for work (maybe updating an account balance in memory) are going to overwrite each other. If these two threads were trying to post two transactions - add 1000, and remove 500 - here is what would happen now that they don't have exclusive access:

- Thread 1: reads '1000' from the account balance.
- Thread 2: reads '1000' from the account balance.
- Thread 1: computes the new balance 1000 + 1000 = 2000.
- Thread 2: computes the new balance 1000 - 500 = 500.
- Thread 1: writes the new balance 2000 to memory.
- thread 2: writes the new balance 500 to memory.

And now because of a threading bug, my account balance is missing $1000.

Comment: yeah, I assume this is what the teacher meant. the next slide suggests that a machine-level Test and Set Lock solution is better because it addresses the problem of checking and setting not being one single instruction. the second alternative is a Semaphor  variable

Comment: @DBRN: "the second alternative is a Semaphor variable" - true, but how do you implement a semaphore :) answer is architecture-level atomic instructions, especially important if you have a multi-core architecture. Ultimately, you have to ask the CPU to perform some sort of atomic instruction. The spinlock page on wikipedia is illuminating: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock